# Sum the elements from a vector using a nested for loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to sum the values of a vector but I have a problem with that.

The size of the vector is 20 elements and I'm trying to do a sum of 5 elements from the current position.

Something like: sum the elements from 1 to 5, 2 to 6, 3 to 7 and so on.

I thought that I could do a for nested loop, like this one below:

```
for (int a = 0; a < numVec.size(); a++) {
    for (int b = a; b < numVec.size(); b++)
    {
        if (aux < 5) {
            cout << "B: " << b << endl;
            sum += numVec[b].num;
        }

        if (aux > 4) {
            aux = 0;
            sumAux= sum;
            sum= 0;
            break;
        }

        aux++;
    }
    cout << "Sum: " << sumAux<< endl;
}
```

But I'm having some problems when I get the 15th position, everything goes wrong and I can't figure out why.

[image: everything goes wrong]

If you can help me, I thank you very much.

Comment: If there are only 20 elements in the list, then anything over 15 will have less than 5 elements to choose from.

Comment: You always `break` out of the loop when `aux = 5` so why not a loop like: `for (int a = 0; a < numVec.size() - 5; a++) { for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) { sum += numVec[a + b].num;....`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp hm right. But how to tell it to sum the remaining numbers anyway? The problem is the "aux > 4" I think, but I don't know what to replace it for.

Comment: But the way that you put the for loop the sum values are not the numbers that I should get.

Comment: Hint. Do it in O(N). Sum the first 5. Call that S(1, 5). Then S(2, 6) is S(1, 5) - element 1 + element 6. No need for an inner loop, and dealing with the end of the vector is simpler. Simpler approach = fewer bugs.

Comment: There seem to be opportunities here for you to clear up the code as it does not look obvious what the code is doing.  I don't think your example contains everything needed to help you.  It seems that aux is used to get out of the inner loop, but you can just add a plus 5 to the guard condition of the inner loop.

Answer (score 4):

It will help you a lot, if you think for a longer time before start to code something. Maybe you can take a piece of paper and write something down.

Then, it will very much help you, if you choose long and speaking variable names.

So, let us make a picuture. We write some test values and their index in the vector, where they are stored. Please remeber. Indices start with 0 in C++.

```
Value:   21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
Index:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

So, and if we now want to build the sums for 5 values each, then we need to add

```
Index   0  1  2  3  4      Value: 21 22 23 24 25
Index   1  2  3  4  5      Value: 22 23 24 25 26
Index   2  3  4  5  6      Value: 23 24 25 26 27

. . . 

Index   14 15 16 17 18     Value: 35 36 37 38 39
Index   15 16 17 18 19     Value: 36 37 38 39 40
```

So, you can see. We have a start index that always will be incremented by 1. Beginning with this start index, we will always add up 5 values. But we must end this process, as you can see above at index 15, so 20 - 5.So, always, size of the whole array - the size of the subarray.

So, let us first solve this problem we can do it strigh forward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Our test data to play with
    std::vector<int> data = { 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40 };
    
    // This is the size of the subarray. So the number of values that we want to sum up
    int sizeOfSubarray = 5;

    // And because we have a subarray size, the last summation starts at this index
    int lastIndex = data.size() - sizeOfSubarray;

    // So, now iterate over all data that needs to be summed up
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex <= lastIndex; ++startIndex) {

        // Because we have a new start index now, we start also with a 0 sum
        int sum = 0;

        // Calculate the end index of the sub array
        int endIndexOfSubarray = startIndex + sizeOfSubarray;
        for (int sumIndex = startIndex; sumIndex < endIndexOfSubarray; ++sumIndex) {

            // Some debug output
            std::cout << "Startindex: " << startIndex << "\tSumindex: " << sumIndex << "\tValue: " << data[sumIndex] << '\n';

            // Calculate the subarray sum
            sum = sum + data[sumIndex];
        }
        // Show the subarray sum
        std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```

OK, understood. What, if we want also to add up the end of the values of the array? So, what if the startindex will rund over the complete array. Let us look at this.

```
Index   16 17 18 19  ?     Value: 37 38 39  40 ?
Index   17 18 19  ?  ?     Value: 38 39 40  ?  ?
Index   18 19  ?  ?  ?     Value: 39 40  ?  ?  ?
Index   19  ?  ?  ?  ?     Value: 40  ?  ?  ?  ?
```

You can see, that the start index runs until < 20. So < size of vector.

And if the is the end index of the summation is > 19, so >= the sizeof the vector, we can limit it to 19,

This we can either calculate or use a simple if statement.

Then the code would look like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // Our test data to play with
    std::vector<int> data = { 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40 };
    
    // This is the size of the subarray. So the number of values that we want to sum up
    int sizeOfSubarray = 5;

    // So, now iterate over all data that needs to be summed up
    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < data.size(); ++startIndex) {

        // Because we have a new start index now, we start also with a 0 sum
        int sum = 0;

        // Calculate the end index of the sub array
        int endIndexOfSubarray = startIndex + sizeOfSubarray;

        // If this index is too big ( > 20) then limit it to 20
        if (endIndexOfSubarray > data.size()) {
            endIndexOfSubarray = data.size();
        }
        // Claculate sum of sub array
        for (int sumIndex = startIndex; sumIndex < endIndexOfSubarray; ++sumIndex) {

            // Some debug output
            std::cout << "Startindex: " << startIndex << "\tSumindex: " << sumIndex << "\tValue: " << data[sumIndex] << '\n';

            // Calculate the subarray sum
            sum = sum + data[sumIndex];
        }
        // Show the subarray sum
        std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```

I hope, this explanation helps

Comment: What an explanation... 100% understandable. Thanks so much for the time consumed to build this answer.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to have the inner loop range from `0-5`

```
for (int a = 0; a < numVec.size(); a++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < 5 && a + b < numVec.size(); b++) {
         sum += numVec[a + b];
    }
    std::cout << sum << "\n";
}
```

Another option is to use `std::accumulate`

```
for (auto a = numVec.begin(); a < numVec.end(); a++) {
    std::cout << std::accumulate(a, std::min(a + 5, numVec.end()), 0) << '\n';
}
```

Also, mentioned in the comments by @Bathsheba is to keep a running total, which is O(n).

```
int sum = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < 5 && a < numVec.size(); a++) sum += numVec[a];
std::cout << sum << '\n';
for (int a = 5; a < numVec.size(); a++) {
    sum = sum - numVec[a - 5] + numVec[a];
    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is considered to be the rolling sum etc. You could write a template that manipulates a binary function on the vector specifying the window:

```
# include <iostream>
# include <numeric>
# include <vector>
# include <functional> 
using namespace std;

template<class T, class Lambda>
vector<T> roll_fun(vector<T> vec, int window, Lambda&& func, T init){
    int final_size =  vec.size() - window + 1;
    vector<T> result(final_size);
    for (int k = 0; k < final_size; k++)
      result[k] = accumulate(vec.begin() + k, vec.begin() + k + window, init, func);
    return result;
};


int main() 
{  vector<double> myvec{1,2,2.3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    //rolling sum
    vector<double> v = roll_fun<double>(myvec, 5,plus<double>(), 0.0);
    for(auto i: v) cout<<i<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    
    // rolling mean
    vector<double> v1 = roll_fun<double>(myvec, 5,[](double x, double y){return x+y/5;}, 0);
    for(auto i: v1) cout<<i<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    
     //rolling max
    vector<double> v2 = roll_fun<double>(myvec, 5,[](double x, double y){return x>y?x:y;}, 0.0);
    for(auto i: v2) cout<<i<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole `aux` and `sumAux` handling is making your logic more complicated than it needs to be.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

const size_t size = numVec.size();
const size_t increment = 5;

for (size_t a = 0; a < size; ++a)
{
    size_t stop = a + std::min(size-a, increment);

    sum = 0;
    for (size_t b = a; b < stop; ++b)
        sum += numVec[b].num;

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/400nkx)

Alternatively:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

auto end = numVec.end();
decltype(numVec)::difference_type increment = 5;

for (auto start = numVec.begin(); start != end; ++start)
{
    auto stop = start + std::min(end-start, increment);

    sum = std::accumulate(start, stop, 0,
        [](auto a, const auto &elem){ return a + elem.num; }
    );

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/WSFeAg)

Comment: Wow, I was actually doing that more complicated that it is... Thank you so much. I just don't understand the usage of the std::min there

Comment: [`std::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) takes 2 inputs and returns whichever one has a lower value. Since you want to process no more than 5 elements at a time, I'm using `std::min()` to limit the sum to 5 elements if there are more than 5 elements remaining, otherwise I sum just the remaining elements, eg: `std::min(6, 5)=5, std::min(4, 5)=4` Like JohnnyMopp said in comments, "*If there are only 20 elements in the list, then anything over 15 will have less than 5 elements to choose from.*"